# Is this the proper way to wait for this function to finish before calling it again?(React-Native)

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function that listens to Firestore database and fetches some data in realtime. Then it calls another function to make a calculation. Now, I wanna know if I am doing it the right way because I dont want the first function to call the second one before the second one is finished.

```
_fetchPatientsList() {
    function onResult(QuerySnapshot) { //first function
        this.setState({ dataSource: QuerySnapshot });
        this._calculateLocationDistance(); //second function
    }

    firestore()
        .collection('coolection').doc().collection('public')
        .where('act', '==', 1)
        .orderBy('time', 'asc')
        .limit(10)
        .onSnapshot(onResult, onError);
}

_calculateLocationDistance = () => {
  //some calculations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have full context on what you're building but according to the docs, `onSnapshot` runs anytime the document's contents change. That may or may not be exactly what you want.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

If you just want to guarantee ordering of the functions, you could do:

```
firestore()
        .collection('coolection').doc().collection('public')
        .where('act', '==', 1)
        .orderBy('time', 'asc')
        .limit(10)
        .then(onResult)
        .catch(onError);
```

or with async/await syntax:

```
try {
  const result = await firestore()
        .collection('coolection').doc().collection('public')
        .where('act', '==', 1)
        .orderBy('time', 'asc')
        .limit(10)

  onResult(result);
} catch (err) {
  onError(err);
}
```

Comment: actually I was asking about when I call the `_calculateLocationDistance` function.

Comment: Could you clarify which function you're referring to and their desired order? With your code as written `_calculateLocationDistance` will execute after any change to the document and with the above it'll execute anytime you query the collection.

Comment: I stated that that query is a real-time listener, so it fetch anytime, but I dont want to call `_calculateLocationDistance` before its finished with the previous job. I am calling `_calculateLocationDistance` inside the internal function `onResult`.

Comment: one more thing, it seems like I cant call `_calculateLocationDistance` the way I am doing inside that internal function. Any idea how to call it?

Comment: Yeah. `this` value with a function takes on the value of execution context, whereas with an arrow function it depends on where it is defined. I think if you change onResult to an arrow function it'll get you there.

Comment: I think I understand now.  You don't want a previous fetch/calculate job to start until the previous one is done. What us causing it to fetch so many times? One idea is you could toggle a loading var in component state when fetch starts and calculate finishes,  preventing the user from sending more requests while it is processing previous ones.